# The requirement is to remove three consecutive same characters from a String

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

```
public static void bomberAlgo(String str)
    {
        String newString="";
        String givenString=str;
        for(int i=0;i<givenString.length()-1;i++)
        {
            if(givenString.charAt(i)!=givenString.charAt(i+1))
            {
             newString=newString+givenString.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The new String is "+str);
    }
```

My code is removing two same characters now. e.g if input string is "abcccddefgggh" then output should be "abddefh"

Comment: Have you thought about what happens when you get to the end of the string?  If the second to last character _isn't_ the same as the last character, what copies it?  I am sure that is not the perhaps output - because you actually print the original string, not the new string.  What does the output annually look like?

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure about removing 3 consecutive chars, a straightforward approach would be-

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
 for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
     if(i+2 < str.length() && str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i+1) && str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i+2)) {
          i+=2;
          continue;
     }
     sb.append(str.charAt(i));
 }
 System.out.println("The new String is "+ sb);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to count how many times a character repeats before deciding whether to output it or not. See below:

```
static String removeConsecutive(String s, int minRepeatsToRemove) {
    int pos = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (pos < s.length()) {
        char c = s.charAt(pos);
        int repeats = 1;
        while (pos + repeats < s.length() && c == s.charAt(pos + repeats))
            repeats++;

        if (repeats < minRepeatsToRemove)
            for (int i = 0; i < repeats; i++)
                sb.append(c);

        pos += repeats;
    }

    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(removeConsecutive("abcccddefgggh", 3));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package org.apache.log4j;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int len = sc.nextInt();
        String str;

        String[] arr = new String[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            str = sc.next();
            arr[i] = "";
            String temp = str;
            for (int j = 0; j < (temp.length() - 3);) {
                if (temp.charAt(j) == temp.charAt(j + 1) && temp.charAt(j) == temp.charAt(j + 2)) {
                    temp = temp.substring(0, j) + "" + temp.substring(j + 3);
                    j = j + 3;
                } else {
                    arr[i] = arr[i] + temp.charAt(j);
                    j = j + 1;                    
                }
            }
            if (temp.length() > 2) {
                if (arr[i].length() != 0) {
                    if (!(str.charAt(str.length() - 3) == str.charAt(str.length() - 2)) || !(str.charAt(str.length() - 3) == str.charAt(str.length() - 1))) {
                        if (!(str.charAt(str.length() - 3) == str.charAt(str.length() - 5)) || !(str.charAt(str.length() - 3) == str.charAt(str.length() - 4))) {
                            arr[i] = arr[i] + str.charAt(str.length() - 3) + str.charAt(str.length() - 2) + str.charAt(str.length() - 1);
                        } else {
                            arr[i] = arr[i] + str.charAt(str.length() - 2) + str.charAt(str.length() - 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                arr[i] = temp;
            }           
            if (arr[i].length() == 0) {
                System.out.println("-1");
            } else {
                System.out.println(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```